# Connect Ubuntu to LG TV Issue

Tags: xorg, nvidia, resolution, hdmi, tv

i got a LG 32 INCH TV (LG 32PC51) and i try to connect it to GEFORCE 8600GS 512MB CARD , i tried HDMI, VGA and i cannot make it look good without flicking or something that fits to that screen. My friend told me that NVidia cards general do issues with Linux and he solved it by buying a simple ATI or other company's card 
I need very simple card it's just to view the desktop and sometimes work on it, no games, graphics etc. needed. Cheap card
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This May be a dumb answer, I’m running Ubuntu on a 32LG3000,

Mine is only HDReady "1366 x 768 " and by default I got the FullHD "1920x1080" resolution.

The picture went much better when I edited the resolution to the right one in nvidia control panel.